# AndroidStudio 3.0 compatible gradle build tool

Tags: gradle, android-studio-3.0, androidx

What is the highest version of

```
com.android.tools.build:gradle
```

that Android Studio 3.0 can support?

I'm currently using

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0'
```

with gradle version 4.4.

I tried using

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
```

but AndroidStudio warns about compatibility with gradle version 4.4, even when it's already set to 4.4. I tried using gradle 4.6, 4.10, but the warning keeps popping up. Is this a bug in AndroidStudio 3.0?

I'm asking this question because I'm trying to use androidx.databinding on AndroidStudio 3.0, and there hasn't been many results when googling this topic. Would appreciate any comments about this issue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have an Android project which is successfully building. I'm using the latest version of Android Studio (3.2.1), Gradle 4.7 and Gradle build tools 3.2.1. All working well.

**build.gradle (buildscript subsection):**

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
```

**gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties:**

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.7-all.zip
```

So maybe your issue is that you need to upgrade your Gradle wrapper to download Gradle 4.7 instead?

Comment: Thanks EM-Creations for your reply. The thing is, I need to use AndroidStudio 3.0 (because the project uses Google Cloud Endpoints). So I want to know the compatible libraries that I can use in 3.0. So far, the other androidx libraries can be used, but I am having problems with androidx.databinding. The current configuration build has an error.

Comment: @uan Are you able to use Gradle 4.7 in Android 3.0? Try changing to `gradle-wrapper.properties` file.